# Why does JSON.NET not deserialize certain class members?

Tags: c#, json.net

Say I have a simple class:

```
[DataContract]
class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public Stopwatch swMember { get; set; }

    [DataMember] 
    public SomeEnum enumMember { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool boolMember { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Task taskMember { get; set; }
    public ClassA()
    {
        swMember = new Stopwatch();

    }
}

public enum SomeEnum
{
    x,y,z
}
```

I make an object for A and assign it some values:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.swMember.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
a.enumMember = SomeEnum.z;
a.boolMember = true;
a.taskMember = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => "A");
```

Then I serialize this object and deserialize it into another object:

```
 ClassA a1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassA>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a));
```

This is what serialized version of instance 'a' looks like:

```
{"swMember":{"IsRunning":true,"Elapsed":"00:00:07.0445661","ElapsedMilliseconds":7044,"ElapsedTicks":19218028},"enumMember":2,"boolMember":true,"taskMember":{"Result":"A","Id":1,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}}
```

This is what instance 'a1' looks like
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9WzD.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e3R2.png)
**Then why does the deserialized version retain simple members like the bool value or enum value, and why does it reset complex members like the stopwatch and the task values?**

Comment: the properties `IsRunning,Elapsed,ElapsedMilliseconds` are inside the `swMember` you need to create another class for the properties referencing the `swmember`

Comment: Json.NET doesn't reset anything. What you see are read-only properties. You *can't* set the IsRunning, Elapsed, etc properties of Stopwatch. You can't set the Task's properties either. Both are read-only properties calculated from the object's current (running) state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you serialize a complex object, by default Json.Net serializes all public properties on that object, including the read-only ones.  So for example, on the `Stopwatch` class, you will get properties for `IsRunning`, `Elapsed`, `ElapsedMilliseconds` and `ElapsedTicks` in the JSON.  All of these are read-only.

When you deserialize JSON back into objects, Json.Net constructs new instances of those objects using the default constructor (if possible), then attempts to populate them from the JSON using public property setters.  When the deserializer finds the `IsRunning` and `Elapsed*` properties in the JSON it notices the corresponding properties on the `Stopwatch` class are read-only and cannot be set.  So, it just skips over them.  Consequently, if you inspect the deserialized instance of the `Stopwatch`, it will appear as if it has been reset.  In fact, it has never been started-- *it is a new instance, different from the original instance that you serialized*.  Same idea with the `Task` object.

In practice, it does make much sense to try to serialize things like `Stopwatch` and `Task`.  These classes represent transient operations, not data.